# Php mail only receiving some fields

Tags: php, email

Hello guys first of all yes i know i am a noob and i know my mail form is not secure ;-) with that said i hope you guys can help me with this very annoying problem when i send mails using my mail form i only receive the "Name" field and i cant seem to find the problem i will post my code so you guys can have a look thanks in advance :-)

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit-contact'])){
$ToMail = 'test@hotmail.com';
$Subject = 'Mail fra gameds';
$Header = "From: ".$_POST["email-contact"]."\r\n";
$ReplyTo = "Reply to: ".$_POST["email-contact"]."\r\n";
$ContentType = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$Name = "Name: ".$_POST["name-contact"]."\r\n";
$Email = "Email: ".$_POST["email-contact"]."\r\n";
$Content = "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["textarea-contact"])."\r\n";
mail($ToMail, $Subject, $Name, $Email, $Content) or die ("Fejl");
}
?>
```

Comment: concatenate all your body text into one variable only 3rd argument is for the content... see the docs for arguments http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Check the order of the arguments in the `mail()` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Comment: Why should it send any of the other fields? You're not including them in the `mail()` call?

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl that worked! and for the two other thanks to you too! :)